# Switch between different menu in appbar

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 icon buttons and when i click on one ,it menu should expand and when I click on the 2nd button previous menu should collapse and new menu should open at same time.I am using react js.Please suggest how i can achieve this

Comment: store which item is expanded. That's all. The render method will then collapse the old one automatically.,

Comment: I am new to react. can you help me with how ca I store the state and how to use it in next click

Comment: Unfortunately, this side is made to answer specific, focused questions. We cannot teach you React from scratch.

Comment: I am keeping the state in a const .Can someone tell me how can I change state in on click event for the button

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it is resolved basically I wanted to toggle between 2 different menu options